Interpreting the format specifier in printf("%.-1f", 34.14)
Consider the following invocation of printf():
printf("%.-1f", 34.14);

it specifies a negative precision value of -1. Making this call with glibc, we get:
%0.-1f

is this correct? If so, why?

You tagged this language-lawyer but did not specify the C version in the question and answered with a quote from C 1999. The documentation for the C tag says the latest version of the C standard is used, currently 9899:2018, unless otherwise specified in the question. When tagging language-lawyer you ought to be precise about which version of the language you are asking about. The wording for this changed between 1999 and 2018.

@EricPostpischil: Fair point. I mistakenly assumed that any changes to printf would only be "additive", i.e. new valid syntax, rather than "negative", i.e. making valid syntax invalid.

The wording changed between C11 and C17/18. In C17/18 it says:

§7.21.6.1 The fprintf function
4. [...] The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed either by an asterisk * (described later) or by an optional nonnegative decimal integer; [...]

The way I read it, the behavior when using a negative integer is not defined.
This is not a breaking change since it does not make previously valid programs invalid. The intent was never to allow negative values as pointed out in
DR220 - Definition of "decimal integer" / N32079:

The term "decimal integer" is defined neither in the Standard nor in ISO 2382-1. Therefore it is not possible to tell whether, in each case:

the value may be zero
a non-significant leading zero digit may be used
the value may be negative.



Suggested Technical Corrigendum
Add a new paragraph to 7.1.1:
[#x] A decimal integer is a sequence of digits which may begin with one or more zeros, but is nonetheless interpreted as decimal, not octal.


Technical Corrigendum
In 7.19.6.1P4, which reads in part: "[...] or by an optional decimal integer [...]"
change "decimal integer" to "non-negative decimal integer".


This is a good answer, but it complements the discussion of C99. And - if I compile with -std=c99, I still get the same result from glibc.

@einpoklum I spent some time last night looking for the paper in which this word change was suggested in order to be able to provide the original motivation for it - but I couldn't find such a paper. I assume it was made because someone could come to the conclusion you came, but that it has never had defined behavior. None of the major implementations treats it like a 0 in pre C17/18 mode which supports my assumption. I didn't want to put this assumption in the answer though.

@einpoklum I finally found it. They used "non-negative" instead of "nonnegative" in the defect report which is why I didn't find it at first :-)

I think “nonnegative decimal integer” is still a mistake in the standard, because, having implicitly acknowledged a decimal integer could have a minus sign, it also admits there could be a plus sign, but I do not think it was intended to allow and define printf("%.+1f\n", 34.14);. It probably should have said “unsigned decimal integer” or “nonempty sequence of digits”.

@EricPostpischil I had similar thought when I found the defect report. Looking at the first suggested Corrigendum: "A decimal integer is a sequence of digits which may begin with one or more zeros, but is nonetheless interpreted as decimal, not octal" - there is no room for negatives at all - but they still found it necessary to make that explicit.

I believe that's an error. the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) says:

§7.19.6.1

Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After the %, the following appear in sequence:
... snip ...
- An optional precision ... The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed either by an asterisk * (described later) or by an optional decimal integer;


... snip ...

As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision. ... A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted.


Well, -1 is a negative integer; so it can legitimately be specified literally in the format string; and while the text explaining what to do with a negative specified precision appears in the clause regarding asterisk-indicated values - surely it should be the same logic as for literally-specified values (just like it is for widths).
So, I believe the precision value should be ignored in this cause, and the format string is the equivalent of "%f", so the output should be:
34.140000

(default precision of 6)

The precision integer argument in 5 is not part of the string but an argument to the printf function like:  printf("%.*f", -1, 34.14)

@OfNothing: Indeed, but clause 5 indicates how interpret a negative precision value.
